# disabling a partial view in mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

i have a simple view(A) which has 3 partial views(X,Y,Z) in it. 
A has a tab pane with 3 tabs.
and X,Y,Z are partial views which act as buttons.how ever these are not in

`<button></button>`  tags.

they just appear as two partial views which have a image button in those partial views.
what i want to do is disable/freeze these partial view like when a button is disabled when i navigate to another tab.
please help me out here.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should be done on the client and probably has little to do with Asp.Net MVC 3. Try something like this on the client (using JQuery).

```
$("#button").on('click', function (evt) { $("#partialView").hide(); });
```

Hopefully this helps.